# PHP internal opcode cache

Tags: php, caching

As i am new to PHP i have some question about internal that i am not able to find exactly on internet.

I have read a statement

> PHP recompiles your program every time that it is run into an machine
>   readable language, called opcodes. An opcode cache stores the
>   compilation in memory and just re-executes it when called a second
>   time.

so some question arises in my mind-

1. I read somewhere that PHP cache the **OPCODE** so that no need to *recompile*.  How  can i get to know that if any opcaode caching technique is enabled or not on my server? i am using Xampp with default configuration on my local machine windows.
2. Does *PHP* uses *OPCODE caching* by default or we have to enable it by installing any external library?

Comment: Opcache can actually significantly increase response time. You can enable or disable this in your `php.ini` file.

Comment: Another way to see the settings of the OPcache is to use [phpinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). It shows mine is enabled, and has 647 scripts cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*OPcache* improves *PHP performance* by storing precompiled script bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load and parse scripts on each request.

*phpinfo()* wont show any status of the *OPcache* if the ***Zend OPcache*** extension is not loaded. To check whether is ***Zend OPcache*** loaded or not you can use

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

If *Zend OPcache* is not listed in the array you can configure it in *php.ini* file

Just add in *php.ini*

```
[opcache]
zend_extension ="D:\xampp\php\ext\php_opcache.dll" 
opcache.enable=1
```

Other Configuration of opcache is here https://www.php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php

Also Note that you can configure opcache.enable=1 by only *php.ini*. if you use *ini_set()* it will generate error.

Restart you *xampp php* service and now you can see all configuration by using *phpinfo()*

and finally you can use

```
print_r(opcache_get_status());
```

*opcache_get_status()* will show you all your opcache statistics, cached file , memory consumption etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, opcaching is not enabled by default. You can enable it from the `php.ini`. You do not need to install anything else, it is pre-built in PHP >=5.5.0.

As for the checking, a simple `opcache_get_status()` should do the trick.

I hope this helps. If there is anything unclear, please let me know.