# Does a PHP script/server/page/etc have to be reloaded, reparsed, and executed everytime it's viewed?

Tags: php

I've played around with PHP before, and I ran a small wordpress blog a long time ago. It seems to me that when a visitor loads a PHP page, the server has to reload the PHP file, parse it, and execute it. That would also include loading all the composer autoload files, creating a fresh database connection, running initialization queries like loading configuration from the database, all to render the single page.

In constrast, if I set up a nodeJS server, that code is started, parsed, and run once, and then it sits idle waiting for requests.

I know that servers can compile and cache the opcodes for a page, but it still seems that a script has to reconnect to mysql, do the initialization again, etc.

Is there a way to keep a php server "running" and reuse resources, compilation, configuration, etc. between page views and API requests to the server? Or am I thinking of PHP all wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP internal opcode cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57356428/php-internal-opcode-cache)

Comment: That's why for wordpress you should consider using a cache plugin that will minimize server resources by service static html. As for server language enough to say that database connection costs the same for Node and for PHP.

Comment: So, is the answer that PHP isn't actually the server, and something like nginx or apache can load and cache the PHP code between requests?

Comment: PHP (the "PHP Hypertext **Preprocessor**") is a preprocessor, something that transforms (usually) HTML with embedded PHP code into other HTML. It can do other things, but that's its main use case. Other applications (such as nginx or Apache) act like servers. Whenever a request is received, it's passed to PHP to process it, and the output is sent to the client.

Comment: To process a request, PHP reads the PHP file the server tells it to read, it parses it, it runs the code and generates output. Every time, from top to bottom, for every request. To optimize this flow, there are PHP extensions (such as OPcache) which cache the result of parsing the PHP source code text, so PHP doesn't need to do that again with the next request if the text hasn't changed.

Comment: NodeJS is what's called an "application server". It processes the requests itself and you can write code that has full control over the lifecycle of a connection. PHP is not an application server, but rather something very similar to a CGI program. You can think of it like an external program that is started, it's passed some input, it generates some output, then it's terminated.

Comment: You're right about the build-it-up / use-it / burn-it-down cycle of php. There's lots and lots and lots work being done on optimization  -- opcode caching, WordPress persistent object caches, php-fpm.  Many php sites work at large scale.